# Fix repetitive instance declarations for algebraic data type

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

Let's say I had an algebraic data type `Building`:

```hs
data Building 
  = BRestaurant Restaurant 
  | BStore Store 
  | BHouse House 
  ...
```

`Restaurant`, `Store`, `House`, ... all instance some class. For now let's just use `Show`. I'm currently defining `Building`'s `Show` instance to be:

```hs
instance Show Building where 
  show (BRestaurant a) = show a
  show (BStore a)      = show a
  show (BHouse a)      = show a
  ...
```

This seems pretty repetitive. **Is there a way to apply the show function to the inner data knowing that each element instances show and that each constructor only has one argument?** Am I missing something else that would make this less repetitive? Ideally I'd end up with something like:

```
instance Show Building where 
   show a = applyFunctionMagic show a
```

Comment: The question might not actually be about `Show`, considering the author wrote "For now let's just use Show."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like a good use case for generics.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, TypeOperators #-}

import GHC.Generics
```

We want to implement some `process` function for a generic type:

```hs
data Building 
  = BRestaurant Restaurant 
  | BStore Store 
  | BHouse House
  deriving Generic

process :: Building -> String
process = gprocess . from
```

For that, we define the following `gprocess` function, where we replace the type  `Building` with some parameters `f p`:

```hs
class GProcess f where
  gprocess :: f p -> String
```

And implement it for various type constructors found in GHC.Generics.

We always lift it through `M1` (this instance becomes less trivial when you need to access constructor or field names):

```hs
instance GProcess f => GProcess (M1 i c f) where
  gprocess (M1 x) = gprocess x
```

We are interested in handling sum types, that are represented using `(:+:)`:

```hs
instance (GProcess f, GProcess g) => GProcess (f :+: g) where
  gprocess (L1 x) = gprocess x
  gprocess (R1 y) = gprocess y
```

Finally we handle fields, with `K1`:

```hs
instance Show a => GProcess (K1 i a) where
  gprocess (K1 x) = show x
```

And that's it for ADTs with only one field per constructor.

Full gist: https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/1dd262acbb72231bd4b02b6a8e2fed19

---

For more information about generics:

- A [GHC.Generics tutorial](https://www.stackbuilders.com/tutorials/haskell/generics/)
- The [generics-eot](https://generics-eot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library, a simpler variant of GHC.Generics with more tutorials
- The [GHC.Generics](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html) module documentation
- The [GHC user manual, a section on GHC.Generics](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-DeriveGeneric)

Comment: That's really cool! If I wanted to instance `Building` for more than one class, should I just add another  parameter to `GProcess` that specifies the return type (e.g. `GProcess f r where gprocess :: f p -> r`)? Then when I instance it for `Show` I would specify the return type as String (using newtype if necessary)?

Comment: Sure, that's one possible generalization.